# recovering from locked sync.Mutex

Tags: go

I am attempting to unlock a mutex if it is locked. However, that produced a runtime error so I thought that I would use the recover method:

```
package main

import "sync"

func main() {
    var l sync.Mutex
    l.Lock()
    l.Unlock()

    defer func() {
        if recover() != nil {
            // the return result can be altered 
            // in a defer function call

        }
    }()

    l.Unlock()  

}
```

However, even with recover, I still get:

```
fatal error: sync: unlock of unlocked mutex
```

Comment: You can't unlock an already unlocked mutex. Same as you can't lock an already locked mutex.

Comment: Unlocking an unlocked mutex means your program is incorrect, and there is no way to recover.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking...

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted to do is wrap "Unlock" in a method that would only unlock if it was locked.

Comment: @xaav: you really shouldn't have a situation where you don't know if you can unlock a lock. It's a fatal error for a reason, the program's logic is unsound and can't safely continue.

Comment: You might be looking for something using `channel`s, but without more context, we have no idea what you are trying to do, other an unlock an unlocked Mutex, which is impossible.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear You won't get a runtime error trying to lock an already locked mutex. You will just block until the mutex is available to lock again. The only exception is if the current lock holder attempts to lock again without unlocking first or makes a call which will attempt to lock the same mutex, resulting in a deadlock.

Comment: @Gavin correct and thanks, but as he was doing this all in the main routine, I kinda skipped that detail. Plus, it is still true that you can't Lock a locked Mutex. You can call Lock of course, but as you said, it blocks, but it cannot be Locked twice, you'd need a semaphore for that behavior. Can't turn the light switch on if it's already on.

Answer (score -1):

You can defer Unlock the Mutex immediately after locking it so you don't have to remember to unlock it for every return path exiting the function.

Delete l.Unlock under l.Lock() or change it for

```
defer l.Unlock()
```

and delete 2nd l.Unlock

Comment: @downvoters: what's wrong with this answer? Unless I'm missing something, this a valid solution. Upvoted.

Comment: While this is technically correct, it misses the point of the question about recovering from a double unlock. The OP knows that the second `Unlock` is the problem, it's just to demonstrate the runtime error.